# How can I make int and for have a different color

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: Keyword highlighting]

I am trying to change my colors in IntelliJIdea, in particular I am trying to get something more similar to VSCode or Eclipse. But I cannot find a way to change my types to a different color than other keywords - for example, I would like `int` to be green, while `for` is orange. Is there some way to do that? Or do I need to use `Integer` instead of `int` from now on?

Comment: Note that as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623682/using-int-vs-integer Integer and int are not identical, and while your personal preference may be to have a particular color, the implications of using Integer instead of int is 1) it's going to draw attention from every developer that looks at your code because they are not identical, and 2) it's going to reduce performance. To answer your question: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/06/textmate-bundles-in-pycharm/ looks promising.

Comment: @VividKraig Interesting, but after adding a java bundle, I still cannot differentiate those categories. Looking at the files, I would expect a primitive-value setting in the color menu to pop up, is that incorrect?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not dive deep into the article at hand: had I done so, I would have written up a full explanation on how it works. If you do manage to figure out how to specifically customize primatives (or perhaps just specific keywords in general) from that article or somewhere else, please post the full answer below.